# Forçar abertura do teclado

Tags: android, android-layout

Tenho este dialog na minha aplicação

```
public void alertaLocalizar(View v) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.alerta_comum, null);


    Dialog localizar = new Dialog(this);
    localizar.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    localizar.setContentView(view);
    localizar.show();
    }

}
```

E queria forçar a abertura do teclado assim que ele fosse aberto, como posso fazer isso?

E aproveitando a pergunta, gostaria de saber como usar o botão OK do teclado para ter o mesmo efeito do botão OK do alert e não fechar o teclado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para forçar a abertura do teclado use este código :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT, 0);
```

Para esconder o teclado coloque dentro do botão este código :

```
InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
imm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY, 0);
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação do `InputMethodManager` para melhor entendimento :

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html

E complementando com a sua pergunta sobre aonde colocar o código,eu sugiro você criar um evento para tratar sobre o botão OK do teclado para esconder o teclado através do código que eu postei.

Exemplo do botão Enter com evento KeyEvent :

```
    public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER:
          /*Coloque aqui o que irá acontecer caso pressionado o botão*/
          return true;
        }
    return false;
}
```

Dê uma olhada na documentação do evento KeyEvent que irá te ajudar a fazer isto:

https://developer.android.com/training/keyboard-input/commands.html

Comment: Desculpe a ignorancia, mas onde no código eu teria que introduzir?

Comment: Muito obrigado @Falion, consegui exatamente o que eu queria, mas acaba de me surgir um pequeno problema, verifiquei na documentação do  `ImputMethodManager` e não encontrei. Coloquei no botão cancelar, para esconder o teclado, isso acontece normalmente se o teclado estiver aberto, porém quando o usuario clica no Voltar do aparelho, o teclado some, e clicando em Cancelar, ele volta a aparecer. Tem como fazer com que isso não aconteça? Ou melhor ainda, impedir o teclado de sumir, a não ser que clicado no cancelar?

Comment: Você está usando o KeyEvent ? Por que se sim,você pode colocar um if/case que irá verificar que somente se clicado no Cancelar,ele irá fazer sumir o teclado.

Comment: Não, amigo. Não estou utilizando o KeyEvent. O que fiz foi colocar no alerta o IMM para forçar o teclado aparecer quanto mostrado o alerta, e sumir quando clicado em Cancelar no alerta, o que funciona normal. Acontece que quando o teclado já está fechado (O usuario clicou em voltar e o teclado escondeu) e o usuário clica em Cancelar, ao invés de continuar escondido, ele volta a aparecer. Mas acredito ser um Bug já que em testes, vezes voltou a aparecer, outras continuou escondido. Então decidi não utilizar o IMM nesse caso, já que não vai atrapalhar em nada o usuário. Grato pela sua atenção!

Comment: Caso tenha mais dúvidas então,pode perguntar amigo,pois este site é para ajudar quem precisa.Aconselho a você sempre testar seus códigos repetitivamente,para poder ter certeza de onde vem o problema.Se lhe ajudei coloque minha resposta como "Resposta útil".Fico feliz que minha resposta lhe ajudou.

Comment: Obrigado, ainda estou me familiarizando com o site, fiz isso e irei fazer nas próximas também. Vez ou outra tenho algumas dúvidas que podem até serem bem simples, mas sou programador web, não de Android, daí surgiu a necessidade de desenvolver esse app e estou me aventurando. Obrigado pela atenção.